# Getting Labels for Standard Lookup Fields from API

Tags: api, standard-objects

We're building a mobile app that uses Salesforce metadata retrieved through the [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm).  One of the pieces of metadata we need are field labels, in the authenticated user's language.

For example, we want to display the Account Record Type (`RecordType.Name`) so the label should be "Account Record Type" if the user's language is English or "Tipo de registro de cuenta" if the user's language is Spanish.  These are the labels shown in the web interface:

[image: english account record type]
 [image: spanish account record type]

The problem is that the REST API returns the label as "Record Type ID" or "Id. de tipo de registro" when describing the Account object:

[image]

Other standard lookup fields have a similar problem.  "Parent Account" is "Parent Account ID" from the API.

Custom lookup fields don't have this problem.  The label in the UI matches the label in the API.

Any suggestions for getting the correct label?

Comment: Looks like you want the relationship name rather than the field that maintains the relationship. I'll see if I can find the label for the relationship.

Comment: The correct labels are available from the describeLayout method in the SOAP API, but in this case, we want to use the field in a "list view"-type screen, and it should work even if the field is not on any page layouts.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't currently appear to be an equivalent REST API to the SOAP API describeLayout method. Without it I don't think you can get the information you want.

(Happy to be proven wrong by someone on this).

Comment: Looks like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256190/how-to-get-fields-in-page-layout If it's "just" for standard relationships why bite the bullet and just hardcode labels & translations in the app ;)